# Cauchy's integral formula whenre there is 2 points inside the function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following integral:

$$\int_C\frac{1+z^2}{(z-1)^2(z+2i)}dz$$ where $C$ is a circle centered at $0$ and radius $3$.

I think I can't solve it using the Cauchy's formula for derivatives, since there are two points $z_0$ inside the function area, how should I do it?

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: If you can get the residues, Cauchy's integral formula is what you need to use.

Comment: What is the derivatives formula?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean the Cauchy's formula for derivatives, I'm gonna edit it.

Comment: Why can't you solve it using that formula? What did you try?

Comment: @coffeemath maybe expanding $1 + z^2$ to $(1 + zi)(1-zi)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos there's over two points $z_0$ inside the function area

Comment: Bixinha: I see only points $1$ and $-2i$ inside the ccontour at which function is non analytic.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a partial fraction decomposition, you get$$\require{cancel}\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)^2(z+2i)}=\frac{\frac{9}{25}+\frac{12 i}{25}}{z+2i}+\frac{\frac{16}{25}-\frac{12i}{25}}{z-1}+\frac{\frac{2}{5}-\frac{4i}{5}}{(z-1)^2},$$and so\begin{align}\int_C\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)^2(z+2i)}\,\mathrm dz&=\int_C\frac{\frac{9}{25}+\frac{12 i}{25}}{z+2i}\,\mathrm dz+\int_C\frac{\frac{16}{25}-\frac{12i}{25}}{z-1}\,\mathrm dz+\int_C\frac{\frac{2}{5}-\frac{4i}{5}}{(z-1)^2}\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi i\left(\frac{9}{25}+\cancel{\frac{12 i}{25}}+\frac{16}{25}-\cancel{\frac{12 i}{25}}\right)\\&=2\pi i.\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain a bit the fraction decomposition?

Comment: You write$$\frac{z^2+1}{(z-1)^2(z+2i)}\quad\text{as}\quad\frac A{z-1}+\frac B{(z-1)^2}+\frac C{z+2i}$$and you compute $A$, $B$, and $C$ by doing$$\frac A{z-1}+\frac B{(z-1)^2}+\frac C{z+2i}=\frac{A z^2+C z^2-(1-2 i) A z+B z-2 C z-2 i A+2 i   B+C}{(z-1)^2 (z+2 i)}$$and then solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-2iA+2iB+C=1\\(-1+2 i) A+B-2 C=0\\A+C=1.\end{array}\right.$$